# Calculating the variance matrix Σ of a dataset in a faster way

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to calculate he variance matrix `Σ` with the formula `Σ=E(XX^T)−μμ^T`.

So, I tried this code...

```
def fast_calc(X):

    colsum=np.sum(X,axis=0)
    X=X[:,colsum!=0]
    return X.dot(X.T)

    Y=np.empty([X.shape[0],X.shape[0]])
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i,X.shape[0]):
            Y[i][j]=sum(X[i,:]*X[j,:])
            Y[j][i]=Y[i][j]
    return Y
```

But, it's not fast at all... is there a way to calculate it faster with numpy/scipy??

Comment: Have you tried `numpy.var`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.var.html

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `np.var` .?

Comment: **1.** builtin solution: `np.var` does not compute the covariance matrix but [`np.cov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) does.

Comment: **2.** The function has problems in at least three aspects: **a)** it returns after `return X.dot(X.T)`, so anything below that line is never executed (but this should be pretty fast :p) **b)** it should probably divide by `N` at various places to get the expected value (assuming you want the variance rather than the sum of squares) **c)** where does it subtract the `μμ^T` from the `E(XX^T)` part?

Comment: **3.** Please provide some missing information: What is the shape of `X` and what meaning do you associate with its dimensions? How do you tell it runs too slow, and how fast would you expect it to be?